# jQuery.css('display') only returns inline

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to get checked options from a table which are set `inline`. There is a search function, which sets `$(element).css('display','none')` on objects in which there is no match with the search. Anyways, this piece of code will only return `inline`, no matter what the elements are set to. Even if I manually set all of them to `display: none` in the table itself, the alert will return `inline` for every single object in the table. Is there any solution to this?

**JS code:**

```
function pass_QR() {
    var i = 0;
    var array = [];
    $("input:checkbox:checked").each(function () {
        i++;
        alert($(this).css('display'));
        if ($(this).val() !== 0 && $(this).css('display') === 'inline') {
            array.push($(this).val());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Works for me: http://jsbin.com/edomat/1 My guess would be the ones you've set to `display: none` are also not checked.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to use: `$("input:checked:visible").each` ?

Comment: @kayen: Then `i` would have a different value. It's being incremented regardless of whether the checkbox is visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally, `css("display")` does work, so something else is going on.

I suspect one of two things:

1. The checkboxes that you're making `display: none` are never `checked`, and so you don't see them in your `each` loop.
2. You're **not** making the checkboxes `display: none`, but instead doing that to some ancestor element of them. In that case, `$(this).is(":visible")` is what you're looking for.

Here's an example of #2: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/edomat/2) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/edomat/2/edit)

```
<div id="ancestor">
<input type="checkbox" checked>
</div>
<script>
$("#ancestor").css("display", "none");
console.log("display property is now: " +
    $("input:checkbox:checked").css("display"));
console.log("visible tells us what's going on: " +
    $("input:checkbox:checked").is(":visible"));
</script>
```

...which outputs:

```
display property is now: inline-block
visible tells us what's going on: false
```

Applying that to your code:

```
function pass_QR() {
    var i = 0;
    var array = [];
    $("input:checkbox:checked").each(function () {
        i++;
        alert($(this).css('display'));
        if ($(this).val() !== 0 && $(this).is(':visible')) {
        // Change is here -----------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            array.push($(this).val());
        }
    });
}
```

Side note: Every time you call `$()`, jQuery has to do some work. When you find yourself calling it repeatedly in the same scope, probably best to do that work *once*:

```
function pass_QR() {
    var i = 0;
    var array = [];
    $("input:checkbox:checked").each(function () {
        var $this = $(this); // <=== Once
        i++;
        alert($this.css('display'));
        if ($this.val() !== 0 && $this.is(':visible')) {
        // Other change is here -------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            array.push($this.val());
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try following:

```
$("input:checkbox:checked").each(function(i,o){       
      console.log($(this).css("display"));       
});
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/BcfvR/2/

Comment: check it again. i think thats what you looking for. i hope it helps.

Comment: And now it's back to being a "works for me"-style non-answer. It's great you're trying to help, but frankly, this isn't helpful.